# Linux serial communication, php script issue

Tags: php, linux, serial-port, usb

I am trying to communicate with a micro controller trough a serial port under Linux.
I am using a USB to serial cable for the purpose, but my php script is giving me the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function deviceSet()**

Here is my script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');     //displays php errors

include("php_serial.class.php");

$serial = new phpSerial();

deviceSet('ttyUSB0'); //for linux serial /dev/ttySP(0-4) for usb /dev/ttyUSBN

// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed 
//$serial->deviceClose();
$serial->confBaudRate(9600); //Baud rate: 9600
$serial->confParity("none");  //Parity (this is the "N" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confCharacterLength(8); //Character length (this is the "8" in "8-N-1")
    $serial->confStopBits(2);  //Stop bits (this is the "1" in "8-N-1")
$serial->confFlowControl("none");

$serial->deviceOpen();
// To write into $serial->sendMessage("1");
$read = $serial->readPort();
```

I have my doubts that the php_serial.class file has trouble running the serial connection through USB, any ideas?

Also it seems like there is a problem with this:

```
# dmesg | grep tty
console [tty0] enabled
usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: ftdi_submit_read_urb - failed submitting read urb, error -1
```

Thanks.

I edited the $serial ->deviceSet() and now a bunch of errors appear

Specified serial port is not valid in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 111 Warning: Unable to set the baud rate : the device is either not set or opened in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 204 Warning: Unable to set parity : the device is either not set or opened in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 254 Warning: Unable to set length of a character : the device is either not set or opened in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 298 Warning: Unable to set the length of a stop bit : the device is either not set or opened in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 335 Warning: Unable to set flow control mode : the device is either not set or opened in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 376 Warning: The device must be set before to be open in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 137 Warning: Device must be opened to read it in /var/www/html/php_serial.class.php on line 474

Is this a problem with the php_serial.class

Comment: `deviceSet()` is not a native PHP function. Where are you expecting it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deviceSet()` is a method of the serial class. The way you're calling it, it would need to be a native PHP function.

It should be: `$serial->deviceSet('ttyUSB0');`